# What if an answer is downvoted, but later corrected?

Tags: support, answers, down-votes, post-ban

Recently I wrote an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695582/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-curve-to-have-infinite-length/1695724#1695724). Initially it was incorrect, but now I feel that I have corrected it to the best of my knowledge. There is no other answer on the question either. [Another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698835/find-if-a-vector-is-between-2-vectors/1698906#1698906) was downvoted similarly, although it was correct in the first place, as even the original poster has acknowledged my answer to be legit, although he hasn't upvoted it. I wouldn't bother so much about it, but now I am unable to post an answer to other questions (answer ban has been imposed on my account).

What am I supposed to do in this deadlock? Should I request the original poster to upvote my answer (I consider it impolite)? Or does it need moderator attention? Or should I delete both answers, so that I can start anew? (I have contributed only two answers so far and am willing to contribute more...)

Comment: This seems related: [How do I get out of the answer block?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17030/how-do-i-get-out-of-the-answer-block) However, it is rather old post, it is possible that some information given there is already obsolete.

Comment: BTW deleted posts are taken into account, too. See: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: And I will also mention that according to [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19570/if-banned-from-asking-questions-can-i-still-answer-questions/19571#19571) your answer ban is probably not permanent. Quote: "However, question-bans and answer-bans are nowadays not permanent - unless you try really hard - they age away, and mostly are but a rate-limiting."

Comment: I read some parts of your links, and all of them scared me. Apparently, this could've turned into a permanent problem for me. But then, all i did was wrote a wrong answer initially. And when i corrected it, no one was around to see that! What could i have done if no-one had paid attention to those? I have already corrected my mistakes, i believe!

Comment: "But then, all i did was wrote a wrong answer initially." Everybody can make mistakes *sometimes*, but you should avoid trying to answer question were you are not confident to know the answer. In brief: do not post attempts or tentative answers.

Comment: @quid I will keep that in mind while posting my next answers. Thank you everyone for your views!

Comment: @quid: "In brief: do not post attempts or tentative answers." For questions with complete answers, this is probably good advice, but for some difficult questions, attempts or tentative answers might be all that can be given.

Comment: @robjohn yes, I certainly agree, and even meant to make this explicit, but then decided instead for a clear instructions *for this user* (at this point in time).